# Converting u_char to char

Tags: c, char

I have a function that returns a value in `u_char` array. Is there any way to convert this into a `char` string.

Here is what I have:

```
u_char *buf = NULL;
size_t out_len = 0;
```

`out_len` returns the number of characters updated buy my function.
Also I am not sure whether `buf` is null terminated or not.
I have tried `printf("%.*s",buf_len, buf);` but that dosn't seem to work.

Comment: sprintf() does it (or memcpy/strcpy) but this is implementation dependant. Moreover please note that number of items in a char array isn't equivalent to number of characters (because of encoding and culture specific definition of character).

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, `printf("%.*s", buf_len, buf);` will look for NULL terminated string.

One solution is that copy all the characters into an array using `strncpy`.

```
strncpy(my_array, (const char *)buf, buf_len);
```

Ensure that `my_array` should be large enough to hold `buf` and a NULL character.